# Highcharts.js: how can stacked area graph animations be smooth?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to make a realtime-updating stacked area graph in Highcharts.js. The problem is that the "area" of the graph disappears during .addPoint() animation.

I'm trying to achieve this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/DgKKX/5/

...But when I try it for area graphs, this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/DgKKX/6/

Anyone got a clue on how to make the "area" animate as well?

Comment: Works if you disable stacking: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgKKX/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try duration and easing options of animation property similar to [jsfiddle.net/DgKKX/5](http://jsfiddle.net/DgKKX/5/)

Maybe you could also change area to 'areaspline' so that graph will be smooth